# Regex & Sed: How to suppress the first and the second comma in a string containing exactly 9 commas?

Tags: regex, awk, sed, replace, terminal

I would like to suppress the two first commas in a string containing 10 and only 10 commas (11 Fields). I don't want to erase the commas of the 9 commas line.

I tried this:

```
sed '/^\([^,]*,\)\{10\}[^,]*$/s/,//1;s/,//2'
```

But it deletes commas even in the sentences containing less than 10 commas and it deletes the first and the third commas.

Example:

```
DE, LAEIES,Vlzgstraat, 16,2260,NIJLEN,BELGIË,06346641,0636641,NL
Leonarfdsdy Dandfiel, Ingendfdfdfieur - Leon.ing,rombach, Hinderusen, 485,47580,SANKT VITH,BELGIQUE,0442345,2058560,FR
```

Result expected:

```
DE, LAEIES,Vlzgstraat, 16,2260,NIJLEN,BELGIË,06346641,0636641,NL
Leonarfdsdy Dandfiel Ingendfdfdfieur - Leon.ing rombach, Hinderusen, 485,47580,SANKT VITH,BELGIQUE,0442345,2058560,FR
```

Comment: Please add sample input and your desired output for that sample input to your question.

Comment: You need to replace the `2` in the regex with `1` again; you've already eliminated the first comma with the previous substitution, so now you want to eliminate the current first comma.  Or reverse the order of the `s/,//1` and `s/,//2` commands.

Comment: Find lines containing exact 10 commas and then remove first comma and then remove **first** comma.

Comment: You also have to put the two substitutions between curly brackets if you want these one to be in factor with your conditonal pattern.

Comment: @Cyrus the problem if I do that, it is that it is erasing the lines that contains 9 and 8 commas too. I would like to limit only to the 10 commas.

Comment: I suggest: `echo "1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0," | sed '/^\([^,]*,\)\{10\}[^,]*$/{s/,//;s/,//}'`

Comment: Your example has only nine commas.

Comment: @Cyrus You are right, I corrected the question

Comment: @Cyrus I tried to put the {} with the line : sed '/^\([^,]*,\)\{10\}[^,]*$/{s/,//1;s/,//2}' but I got an error message "bad flag in substitute command: '}'"

Comment: This might work without GNU sed and 9 commas: `echo "1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9," | sed '/^\([^,]*,\)\{9\}[^,]*$/s/,//; /^\([^,]*,\)\{8\}[^,]*$/s/,//'` Output: `123,4,5,6,7,8,9,`

Comment: @Cyrus It works for the 9 commas lines, but the problem is that is change all the 8 commas lines too...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you're using MacOS sed / BSD sed, try this:

```
sed -e '/^\([^,]*,\)\{10\}[^,]*$/s/,//; tLB' -e 'b' -e ':LB' -e 's/,/ /'
```

I used `--posix` to emulate, but not sure it will work on your OS:

```
$ cat file
DE, LAEIES,Vlzgstraat, 16,2260,NIJLEN,BELGI?,06346641,0636641,NL
Leonarfdsdy Dandfiel, Ingendfdfdfieur - Leon.ing,rombach, Hinderusen, 485,47580,SANKT VITH,BELGIQUE,0442345,2058560,FR

$ sed --posix -e '/^\([^,]*,\)\{10\}[^,]*$/s/,//; tLB' -e 'b' -e ':LB' -e 's/,/ /' file
DE, LAEIES,Vlzgstraat, 16,2260,NIJLEN,BELGI?,06346641,0636641,NL
Leonarfdsdy Dandfiel Ingendfdfdfieur - Leon.ing rombach, Hinderusen, 485,47580,SANKT VITH,BELGIQUE,0442345,2058560,FR
```

Note that the second `s` command, I changed to replace to a `space`, since `Leon.ing,rombah` no space inside, simpy strip the `,` will become `Leon.ingrombach`.

This might work too:

```
sed -e '/^\([^,]*,\)\{10\}[^,]*$/{' -e 's/,/ /' -e 's/,/ /}'
```

Btw, I think it's high time for you to start using GNU sed:

```
brew install gnu-sed
ln -s /usr/local/bin/gsed /usr/local/bin/sed
```

This problem is also easier to use `awk` instead:

```
awk -F, 'NF==11{sub(",","");sub(","," ")}1' file
```

Replace only when there're 11 comma separated fields.

Comment: In your ask script: What does the `1` after the `}` do?

Comment: @cars10m  It represents `true`, when no block given, `{print $0}` is implied. So it bascially equals `"True"{print $0}`. -- Note there's no explict `true` or `false` boolen in `awk`.

Comment: Ah, I got it in the end: the `1` acts like an "always true" condition and, as it is not followed by anything else, awk's default command `{print}` is applied.

Answer (score 3):

You may use

```
sed -E 's/^([^,]*),([^,]*),([^,]*)((,[^,]*){7})$/\1\2\3\4/'
```

**Details**

- `^` - start of a line
- `([^,]*)` - Group 1 (`\1`): any 0+ chars other than `,`
- `,([^,]*)` - `,` and Group 2 (`\2`) matching any 0+ chars other than `,`
- `,([^,]*)` - `,` and Group 3 (`\3`) matching any 0+ chars other than `,`
- `((,[^,]*){7})` - seven occurrences of `,` followed with any 0+ chars other than `,`
- `$` - end of string.

See the [online `sed` demo](https://ideone.com/OprrxM):

```
s="Leonarfdsdy Dandfiel, Ingendfdfdfieur - Leon.inrombach, Hinderusen, 485,47580,SANKT VITH,BELGIQUE,0442345,2058560,FR"
sed -E 's/^([^,]*),([^,]*),([^,]*)((,[^,]*){7})$/\1\2\3\4/' <<< "$s"
# => Leonarfdsdy Dandfiel Ingendfdfdfieur - Leon.inrombach Hinderusen, 485,47580,SANKT VITH,BELGIQUE,0442345,2058560,FR
```

Comment: I tried it, but it seems that it doesn't remove the commas

Comment: @ΩlostA Share the exact code you tried. Also, `sed` and OS version details would help.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/,/&/9;T;s//&/10;t;s///;s///' file
```

If there are not at least 9 `,`'s leave line as is. If there are 10 or more `,`'s leave line as is. Otherwise remove the first 2 `,`'s.

An alternative:

```
sed -r 's/^([^,]*),([^,]*),(([^,]*,){7}[^,]*)$/\1\2\3/' file
```